# Image shows 0 bytes when saving to internal storage?

Tags: java, android

So, I am trying to capture an image and save it in my internal storage of my phone in android. Now, here is the problem. When I check my camera gallery, the image is stored as expected but then when I try to access the image in my computer through USB, it shows 0 bytes. What could I be doing wrong?

```
try {
                   // Thread.sleep(1000);
                    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mrgba.cols(), mrgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Utils.matToBitmap(mrgba, bmp);
                    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp, "file",null);
                   // showPreviews = false;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: @motis10:- No. The picture is saved fine and opens in my phone but when I try to access it in my laptop, it shows 0 bytes.

Comment: @lesley thats the problem of connection between phone and laptop. its not copied completely